# Diag output structure of Qualcomm modems

Tags: diagnostics, wireshark-dissector, qualcomm, data-link-layer, quectel

I have a Qualcomm Quectel EC25 modem which I can send AT-Commands to this module with reciving the response. I store this modem diag bytes using a python opensource app ([qcsuper](https://github.com/P1sec/QCSuper)) with a little code manipulation. Here is a sample diag bytes:

21 00 00 0A 08 01 01 00 00 50 1C 00 04 00 03 03 FF FF 00 FF 11 90 02 00 00 10 00 00 00 EF 1F AA 4C 0B 1E 03 00 00 11 90 02 00 00 00 00 08 01 02 63 ... 02 00 B2 00 4F 00 C0 **7E** 01 00 D2 00 FD 00 C0 8E 00 00 C5 00 C5 01 C0 7E 01 00 BA 00 ... 00 00 00 00 14 **7E** 01 00 50 81 01 00 40 7D 01 00 2C ... 8D 00 00 48 8C 00 00 **7E** 00 00 00 7D 00 00 00 78 00 00

QCSuper can also run Wireshark automatically to dissect RRC Signaling messages.

I had an experience with Qualcomm Snapdragon mobile phone and after receiving the bytes I could dissect them using a specific structure. Some of the patterns of this structures were indicated in a python-c++ opensource app ([mobile-insight](https://github.com/mobile-insight/mobileinsight-core)) e.g. the frames in the diag bytes starts with **98 00** and timestamp and frame type with a specific size follow it. Also **7E** is indicated the end of the frame.

Now, I want to know is there a similar structure in this modem diag outputs to allow for dissecting? Can you offer me a suitable document or app like mobile-insight?